# Ошибка в инструменте asp.net configuration

Tags: asp.net

Запускаю инструмент [asp.net](http://asp.net) configuration. В браузере появляется следующая ошибка: Истек таймаут средства. В качестве меры безопасности средство администрирования веб-узла прекращает работу по истечении его срока действия. Изменения в файлах machine.config или web.config могут вызвать необходимость перезагрузиться. Для продолжения настройки веб-узла перезагрузите средство.

Вот что содержит мой web.config файл. Как исправить данную проблему? Гугл не находит какого-нибудь решения.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="180" defaultProvider="WebChatMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <add applicationName="WebChat" name="WebChatMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="WebChatDB"
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
               enablePasswordReset="true"
               requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
               requiresUniqueEmail="false"
               passwordFormat="Hashed" ></add>
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <httpRuntime appRequestQueueLimit="100" executionTimeout="60000" />
    </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebChatDB" connectionString="Data Source=ANTONLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WebChat;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>
    <add key="DBConnection" value="server=LocalHost;uid=sa;pwd=;database=WebChat;Connect Timeout=200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите Ваш проект на **`ASP.NET`** в папку, ***максимально приближенную к корню диска***, и не содержащую кириллических символов, а лучше вообще состоящую только из латинских букв.

Пример:

```
C:\ASPNET\MySite
```